# Loop and store key value from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to extract values from a PHP associative array I have created from an SQL query

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(Date) AS weekday, 100 * SUM(Att_Type) / COUNT(Att_Type) AS percentage 
FROM Attendance 
WHERE ID=$ID AND WEEK(Date) = WEEK(NOW()) 
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(Date)
```

which is being stored in the variable `$arr` with the contents I have found using the `print_r` command:

```
Array ( [weekday] => 2 [percentage] => 100.0000 ) 
Array ( [weekday] => 1 [percentage] => 100.0000 ) 
Array ( [weekday] => 0 [percentage] => 66.6667 ) 
Array ( [weekday] => 3 [percentage] => 100.0000 )
```

I'm new to PHP associative arrays and I was wondering how I could create a function where it will take the value of the weekday key, if it is 0 (Monday), store the value of the percentage key in the Monday variable and so on for the rest of the weekday values available up to 4 (Friday).

EDIT:

The output I am looking for is where the values are saved to independent variables so when called they plainly display the value such as:

```
$monday = 66.6667
$tuesday = 100.0000
$wednesday = 100.0000
$thursday = 100.0000
$friday = 0 //when there is no value corresponding to that weekday in the array then it will be 0
```

so they can be echoed later in the code.

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/H8lJa) might help. Use an array to map the 'indices' to days.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include an explicit example of what sort of output you're looking for? Either show a code example of which variables you want defined at the end, or what text you'd want output.

Comment: @jibsteroos I really like that example, but I keep getting an error 'Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [['weekday' => 2, 'percentage' => 100.0000,], ['weekday' => 1, 'percentage' => 100.0000,], ['weekday' => 0, 'percentage' => 66.6667,], ['weekday' => 3, 'percentage' => 100.0000,]];    

$days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'];

foreach ($days as $day) {
    ${$day} = 0;
}
```

If you're using `$results = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to get the array of the results use this;

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $arr) {
    ${$days[$arr['weekday']]} = $arr['percentage'];
    // $arr['weekday'] gets the weekday of the array;
    // $days[$arr['weekday']] gets the day index from the days array
    // ${$days[$arr['weekday']]} then creates a variable with the particular weekday as the variable name
}
```

Or if you're using `while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

```
while ($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ${$days[$arr['weekday']]} = $arr['percentage'];
}
```

Comment: Is the error line in the `foreach` loop? @McKenzieJo

Comment: Cheers mate :) @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: @a.mola um no, it's in the ${$days[$d['weekday']]} = $d['percentage']; line.

Comment: try echoing out the variables before assigning it. Like `echo $days[$d['weekday']];`

Comment: It would help to first do a foreach (or [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) over $days to initialize set all "day" variables to 0.

Comment: @a.mola woo!! Ok, I got it to work in a separate file and it's perfect! I found out why I was getting those errors; I'm trying to use this statement inside a while($arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) to fetch the data from the database, and the $arr does not play nice with your code. I need to figure out why it isn't behaving in the same way :/ any ideas?

Comment: Well you could either call `$array = (mysqli_fetch_all($result), MYSQLI_ASSOC)` to get all the record rows at once or look at my edited answer